# How to Include a video in cakephp .ctp file

Tags: cakephp

I used html helper to work with image in this way and it is working.
In html `<img src="img/photo.jpg">`
In Cakephp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('photo.jpg'); ?>
```

What should I do to include a video

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-videos-and-audio-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 <?= $this->Html->media('video.mp4', [
     'fullBase' => true,
     'text' => 'Fallback text'
 ]) ?>
```